# Powershell Winform RichTextBox Colors?

Tags: winforms, powershell

I've been hunting for a solution to this problem.  (Attempted to decode these with little success:  http://poshcode.org/4123 http://poshcode.org/4123 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd30h2yb(v=vs.110).aspx)

This seems like it should be something simple, yet I'm struggling to figure this out.  It seems the only way to do this is by using selectionstart, selectionlength, selectioncolor and then cancelling the selection when it prints.  I'm guessing I might have to figure out algorithmically a way to select only the locations of the richtextbox I want.  I wanted to ask before trying to do that though.

**Questions:**

How do you choose to start the selection on a different line?

Is there a way to color only the selection I want without manually selecting the location in the richtextbox?**?

Is there a generally better way to accomplish this?

Also, does anyone know of any good resources or references for Winforms specific to Powershell?

Please help.  Thanks.

**Here's what I'm attempting to do:**

```
function UserInformation {
    $userdata = Get-ADUser $34 -properties *

 ## IF LOCKED OUT, MAKE RED ##
    if ($userdata.lockedout -eq $false) {
        $outputBox.SelectionStart = #????
        $outputBox.SelectionLength = #????
        $outputBox.SelectionColor = [Drawing.Color]::Green

    elseif ($userdata.lockedout -eq $true) {
        $outputBox.SelectionStart = #????
        $outputBox.SelectionLength = #????
        $outputBox.SelectionColor = [Drawing.Color]::Red

    }

## GUI ##
    $outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox #creating the text box
    $outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(5,40)
    $outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(565,200)
    $outputBox.MultiLine = $True
    $outputBox.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right -bor 
                    [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top -bor [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left 
    $outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
    $Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your post is almost a year old and you probably got your solution already, but I am having good luck using the RichTextBox form by using the ForeColor property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is my code in PowerShell:

```
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(8,175) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(870,428) 
$outputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Lucida Console",16)
$outputBox.ForeColor = [Drawing.Color]::Green
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ReadOnly = $True
```

And then in lines as necessary (changing to Green in this example)

```
$outputBox.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS",14)
$outputBox.ForeColor = [Drawing.Color]::Green
$outputBox.text="Please standby as we connect to Office 365.  Updating commands ..."
```

Comment: This will not work. It will change the color of the entire text in the `RichTextBox`

Answer (score 0):

To have this working you'll need to add a selection before each newly added line. The New line has to be added via:

```
AppendText()
```

Additionally you'll have to set a line break at the end with **`n** for a new line.

```
$outputBox.SelectionColor = [Drawing.Color]::Green
$outputBox.AppendText("text here...`n")
```